# Ion-checkbox inside anchor tag

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework, anchor

Using ionic 1 I'm having problems with creation `<ion-checkbox>` elements inside an `<a>` tag.

I know it's best to avoid nesting objects inside an anchor tag, however this is currently something I cannot do anything about.

Basicly my problem is this:

```
<a>
    <ion-checkbox>Test</ion-checkbox>
</a>
```

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2ft565t/1/) to demonstrate. If you remove the anchor tag, everything works.

How can I solve this problem, without removing the `<a>` tag?

I've tried using the `ng-click` directive to `$event.stopPropagation()`, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You say you can't do anything about the anchor tag. Why is that? what is the purpose of the anchor tag? It's likely that it's function can be coded differently to remove this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <ion-checkbox>Test</ion-checkbox>
</a>
```